# Cannot read property value of null

Tags: javascript

I have been learning javascript for 6 months, but I really don't know whats wrong with this .... code?

```
<script>
var search_file_val = document.getElementById('search_textbox').value;
var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = "search_val="+search_file_val;
function search_file()
{
    XHR.open('POST','http://www.bt-mail.sk/somescript.php',true);
    XHR.send(params);
}
</script>
```

Google chrome is telling me this . 
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

I'm sure the Id of element is right.

edit:
the html

```
<input type="text" class="cool_input_box" id="search_textbox" onkeyup="search_file()">
```

edit: no2
removed

Comment: can you show us the html relevant to this js too?

Comment: you are correct in assuming the error is on that line - clearly document.getElementByid is returning null

Comment: `document.getElementById('search_textbox')` is returning `null` - are you calling this before the DOM is loaded?

Comment: Is your `<script>` tag before of after the `<input>` element on your page?

Comment: yes, <script> is in the head

Comment: You just need to move all the code inside the function like the first answer suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var search_file_val = document.getElementById('search_textbox').value;
  var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var params = "search_val="+search_file_val;
  function search_file()
  {
      XHR.open('POST','http://www.bt-mail.sk/somescript.php',true);
      XHR.send(params);
  }
});
</script>
```

Although, you should really not be getting the value unless you have requested to search for the file like:

```
<script>
  function search_file()
  {
    var search_file_val = document.getElementById('search_textbox').value;
    var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = "search_val="+search_file_val;
    XHR.open('POST','http://www.bt-mail.sk/somescript.php',true);
    XHR.send(params);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not  how SO works. I'll try to help where needed, but I can't do the work for you.

Comment: allright :D no problem, I know somewhere is error, I don't want to do work from you, I thought it would be better to show you website instead of some pieces of it